# how to select rows based on two condition pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to filter rows that are in `df_1` that match the following two condition

- Row from `df_1` should not be in `df_2`

  OR
- If row from `df_1` is in `df_2` then it must have a value `Yes` in `df_2`

Code I tried, that does not work

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], 'b': ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No']})

df = df_1[(~df_1.a.isin(df_2.a)) | (df_2.b=='Yes')]
```

Output

```
   a
0  1
2  3
4  5
6  7
8  9
```

Expected Output

```
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  6
4  5
6  7
8  9
```

Explanation
Rows 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 are not in `df_2` so they are part of the output
Rows 2 and 6 are in `df_2` but the have column b as `Yes` so they are part of the output

Comment: `4` has `No` in df_2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = df_1.merge(df_2, how='left', on='a')
print(df[df.b.isin(['Yes', np.nan])][['a']])
```

`OUTPUT`

```
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
4  5
5  6
6  7
8  9
```

Comment: can you explain the list in `isin`? what is the need for that? thanks

Comment: Sure, When you merge `df_1` with `df_2` rows where `df_1` does not match `df_2` will have `nan` in the `b`  column. So when you do `isin([yes, np.nan])`, here `nan` matches your first condition and `yes` matches your second condition. You can print `df` after merging and you will know what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create two frames and concat it as below.

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], 'b': ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No']})

df = [df_1[(~df_1.a.isin(df_2.a))]['a'],df_2[df_2.b=='Yes']['a']]
result = pd.concat(df).sort_values()
print(result)
```

output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your calculation stems from the fact that `df_1` and `df_2` are not the same size and logical operators between their
columns does not make sense.  If you map your values in `df_1` to `Yes`, `No` or `NaN` using `df_2` then you will have equal length columns that can be compared

```
df_1[(~df_1["a"].isin(df_2["a"])) | (df_1["a"].map(df_2.set_index("a")["b"]) == "Yes")]
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't be the fastest solution but the steps should be easy enough for you to follow. When the two dataframes are merged using a union, `NaN` values are added in place of missing data. Afterwards you want to retain those rows so you only need to remove those which have the value `No`.

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], 'b': ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No']})

# Merge the dataframes using a union
df = df_1.merge(df_2, how='outer', on='a')
# Drop the rows where 'b' == 'No'
df.drop(df[df['b']=='No'].index, inplace=True)
# Drop column 'b'
df.drop('b', axis=1, inplace=True)
```